# Upgrade Apache Solr from 4.10.4 to 6.6.0 on Cent os 7

Tags: solr, upgrade, centos7, solr4, solr6

How to upgrade Apache solr from existing version 4.10.4 to 6.6.0 (A latest one)
On linux centos 7 operating system.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**stop existing running solr**

```
sudo service solr stop
```

**confirm its stopped or not**

```
sudo service solr status
```

> You can take backup of existing solr data from
>   /var/solr/data/< core_name >, But reindexing solr data after upgrading
>   solr version will give best performance without any unknown issues.

**now remove existing solr from centos**

```
sudo rm -r /var/solr
```

**remove solr from following location if its there**

```
sudo rm -r /opt/solr
sudo rm /etc/init.d/solr
```

**In my case following path was not exist to delete, Delete if exists in your case**

```
sudo rm -r /opt/solr/solr-4.10.4
```

**remove existing solr user with home directory**

```
sudo userdel -r solr
```

**for ubuntu**

```
sudo deluser --remove-home solr
```

**remove existing group**

```
sudo groupdel solr
```

**for ubuntu**

```
sudo deluser --group solr
```

**restart your system**

```
sudo reboot
```

## Check supporting application and download solr 6.6

**Check which version Java version is installed on your machine**

```
java -version
```

**Check available java versions, and update to latest version**

```
yum list available java*
```

**Install latest java version**

```
sudo yum install <jdk version>
```

**download and extract installation folder**

```
mkdir /home/user/temp
cd temp
wget http://apache.org/dist/lucene/solr/6.6.0/solr-6.6.0.tgz
tar -zxvf solr-6.6.0.tgz
```

**install solr**

```
cd solr-6.6.0/
sudo bin/install_solr_service.sh /home/user/temp/solr-6.6.0.tgz
```

## after successful installation you can see following output

> id: solr: no such user Creating new user: solr
>
> Extracting /home/user/temp/solr-6.6.0.tgz to /opt
>
> Installing symlink /opt/solr -> /opt/solr-6.6.0 ...
>
> Installing /etc/init.d/solr script ...
>
> Installing /etc/default/solr.in.sh ...
>
> Service solr installed. Customize Solr startup configuration in
>   /etc/default/solr.in.sh Waiting up to 180 seconds to see Solr running
>   on port 8983 []   Started Solr server on port 8983 (pid=4802). Happy
>   searching!
>
> ```
>  Found 1 Solr nodes:
> ```
>
> Solr process 4802 running on port 8983 {
>   "solr_home":"/var/solr/data",   "version":"6.6.0
>   5c7a7b65d2aa7ce5ec96458315c661a18b320241 - ishan - 2017-05-30
>   07:32:53",   "startTime":"2017-06-26T07:02:51.523Z",   "uptime":"0
>   days, 0 hours, 0 minutes, 13 seconds",   "memory":"34.4 MB (%7) of
>   490.7 MB"}

**Now check if you can access solr admin panel**

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/
```

**Check if solr is running, start solr if not running and then try**

```
sudo service solr status
```

**If you are still not able to access solr admin panel, then may you OS firewall is blocking to port 8983**

use following commands to allow port 8983 in firewall

```
sudo firewall-cmd --zone = public --add-port = 8983 / tcp --permanent
sudo firewall-cmd --reload
```

> ## For further data migration please see [Migration of solr cores after solr version upgradation from 4.10.4 to 6.6.0 on Cent os 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44760114/migration-of-solr-cores-after-solr-version-upgradation-from-4-10-4-to-6-6-0-on-c/44760115#44760115)