# Migration of solr cores after solr version upgradation from 4.10.4 to 6.6.0 on Cent os 7

Tags: solr, centos7, data-migration, solr4, solr6

I have upgraded apache solr from 4.10.4 to 6.6.0 on Cent os 7 server,
with the help of 
[Upgrade Apache Solr from 4.10.4 to 6.6.0 on Cent os 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44755868/upgrade-apache-solr-from-4-10-4-to-6-6-0-on-cent-os-7/44755869#44755869)

I have taken backup of old solr core namely `sample_core` in `/home/user/old_solr/sample_core` folder

How can I migrate my old solr(4.10.4) data in new solr version (6.6.0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Make sure solr is running**

```
sudo service solr status
```

**Create new solr core by name `sample_core`**

use solr user 
    `sudo su solr`

Create sample_core `/opt/solr-6.6.0/bin/solr create -c sample_core`

> **If you are not able to create a new core due to existing broken core,**
>   **remove broken cores**
>
> ```
> /opt/solr-6.6.0/bin/solr delete -c <core_name>
> /opt/solr-6.6.0/bin/solr delete -c sample_core
> ```
>
> **delete data folders from /var/solr/data/< core_name > folder (If exists)**
>
> exit solr user and use superuser by command `exit`
>
> use root user by command `sudo su`
>
> ```
> rm -r -f /var/solr/data/sample_core
> ```

**copy existing solr schema.xml and solrconfig.xml to newly created core**

use superuser `sudo su`

```
sudo cp -r /home/user/old_solr/sample_core/conf/schema.xml /var/solr/data/sample_core/conf
sudo cp -r /home/user/old_solr/sample_core/conf/solrconfig.xml /var/solr/data/sample_core/conf
```

**make `solr` as owner to moved files**

```
sudo chown -R solr:solr /var/solr/data/sample_core/conf/schema.xml
sudo chown -R solr:solr /var/solr/data/sample_core/conf/solrconfig.xml
```

**restart solr server**

```
sudo service solr restart
```

> ## Reindex solr data
>
> Now you are ready to reindex solr data,  reindexing solr data after upgrading solr version will give best performance
>   without any unknown issues.

## Incase if you want to use old data without reindex

> **I have not tried this practically while migration**

copy sample_core data from backup to solr 6.6 data

```
sudo cp -r /home/user/old_solr/sample_core/data /var/solr/data/sample_core
```

change owner to `solr`

```
sudo chown -R solr:solr /var/solr/data/sample_core/data
```